# Flutter Error: for the file type in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using a prebuild flutter project in which below code is giving error at

> onImageSelected(croppedImage);

Error

> error: The argument type 'CroppedFile?' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'File?'

```
final Function(File?) onImageSelected;

Future<void> selectedImage(BuildContext context, File? image) async {
    // init i18n
    final i18n = AppLocalizations.of(context);

    // Check file
    if (image != null) {

      final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
          sourcePath: image.path,
          aspectRatioPresets: [CropAspectRatioPreset.square],
          maxWidth: 400,
          maxHeight: 400,
          uiSettings:[ AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: i18n.translate("edit_crop_image"),
            toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          )]
    );
      onImageSelected(croppedImage);
    }
  }
```

How should I rectify it?

Comment: Maybe the best idea would be to ask the original programmer. Alternatively, you can create a [mcve] and post that. *At least* post the definition of `onImageSelected`, otherwise there is really no chance you will get an answer you could work with.

Comment: @nvoigt added definition

Comment: 1. [`ImageCropper.cropImage`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image_cropper/latest/image_cropper/ImageCropper/cropImage.html) returns a `Future` that resolves to a `CroppedFile?`.  In other words, it could potentially return `null`.  You must handle that, possibly by conditionally calling `onImageSelected` only if it's not `null`.  2. `CroppedFile` is not a subtype of `File`.  You probably would need to explicitly construct a separate `File` object: `if (croppedImage != null) { onImageSelected(File(croppedImage.path)); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CroppedFile is not a File. You have to create a new File instance from the temporary path given by the image cropper:

```
if(croppedImage != null) {
    onImageSelected(File(croppedImage.path));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ImageCropper returns the type `Future<CroppedFile?>`. So what you have is a variable of type `CroppedFile`.

The callback `onImageSelected` seems to take a variable of type `File?` instead.

By looking at the code, it seems `CroppedFile` is a limited subset of `File`

https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper/blob/master/image_cropper_platform_interface/lib/src/models/cropped_file/base.dart

What might work is to declare the variable of `croppedImage` with the type `File?` like:

```dart
File? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(...);
```

This is also what they show in their examples:

```dart
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';

File? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
      sourcePath: imageFile.path,
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],
      uiSettings: [
        AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false),
        IOSUiSettings(
          title: 'Cropper',
        ),
        /// this settings is required for Web
        WebUiSettings(
          context: context,
          presentStyle: CropperPresentStyle.dialog,
          boundary: Boundary(
            width: 520,
            height: 520,
          ),
          viewPort: ViewPort(
            width: 480,
            height: 480,
            type: 'circle'
          ),
          enableExif: true,
          enableZoom: true,
          showZoomer: true,
        )
      ],
    );
```